# Node.js request - Fetching response values not working

Tags: node.js, node-request

Node.js request - Fetching response values not working

I'm using node.js and request but I'm not able to fetch the desired values 'name'. What am I missing in my setup?

```
request.get({
  url: "http://127.0.0.1:4004/api/search?name=peter"
}, (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
      console.log(error);
      return console.dir(error);
    } else {
      console.log(response.body);
      var getBody = JSON.parse(response.body);
      if (getBody.status == 200) {
        console.log('Response: '+getBody);
        //console.log('Records: '+getBody.records.name[0]);
        console.log('Records: '+getBody.records.name);
        res.render('profile', {
          page:'Profile',
          menuId:'profile',
          data: {},
          errors: {}
        });
      } 
    }
});
```

Console.log:

```
{"status":200,"error":null,"records":[{"id":235,"abc":"235980JFD","name":"Peter Pan"}]}
Response: [object Object]
Records: undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

records is an array so you have to use:

```
console.log('Records: '+getBody.records[0].name);
```